# Add a group header above the sorted table rows in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a big table with around 50-60 table rows..... I have sorted those rows without using any plugin... This is the logic which I used...

```
var trContent = $('#sessionsTable > tbody  > tr');
var data1, data2, finaldata1, finaldata2;
trContent.sort(function (a, b) {
    data1 = $(a).children('td').find(sortingdivId).eq(0);
    finaldata1 = data1.text().toUpperCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''); //.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
    data2 = $(b).children('td').find(sortingdivId).eq(0);
    finaldata2 = data2.text().toUpperCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''); //.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')

    if (finaldata1 < finaldata2) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (finaldata1 > finaldata2) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});

$.each(trContent, function (index, row) {
    $('#sessionsTable').children('tbody').append(row);
});
```

I want to add a header above each sorted list.... I do not want to use any plugins. Is it possible? Also there are no table headers  tags in the table. I need to create the headers dynamically on each sorted group. Please help.

Comment: Can you post a representative demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can experiment with?

Comment: When you say "each sorted list", what do you mean? I only see one list. Can you do something like `$('<thead/>').append(/*columns here*/).appendTo('#sessionsTable');`?

Comment: Hey Jason, "Each sorted list" basically means that currently my data is in this format...

<tr><td>10:45 AM: Data 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>10:45 AM: Data 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>10:45 AM: Data 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>11:15 AM: Data 4</td></tr>
<tr><td>11:15 AM: Data 5</td></tr>

So as you can see, I have the data being sorted by time "10:45 AM" and "11:15 AM"... This is what the sorted list/data is.... I want to have a header above which looks something like this.

10:45 AM
<tr><td>Data 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 3</td></tr>
11:15 AM
<tr><td>Data 4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 5</td></tr>